# Look it to this Statement : System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;

Tags: c#

Look at this statement :

```
messageBox.show( System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name);
```

the output of this statement is :

> Roshan\mohdibrahim.tasal

but i want to display me only :

> mohdibrhaim.tasal

how can i do this?

Answer (score 7):

You can just split the name on the "\" and retrieve the 2nd item.

e.g.

```
System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name.Split('\\')[1]
```

**Edit:**
You'll want to make this safe by first checking for the existence of a backslash - if there isn't one, you just want to take the Name as-is.

Comment: what if there's no "\" in the name (if the machine is *not* part of a domain) ?? Your code will crash....

Comment: True, I'll add a note to clarify

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you trim returned value until `'\'` is reached,
following code does the trick

```
WindowsIdentity current = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
if(current!=null)
{
     string name = current.Name;
     string value = name.Substring(name.IndexOf('\\') + 1);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[Environment.UserName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.username.aspx) should work without any splitting or additional logic.